# Array of Events in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using angular 5 for my project. I am trying to emit event from a child component like

```
@Output studentUpdated:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()
updated(e){
   this.studentUpdated.emit(e);
}
```

and listing in parent component like

```
<student (studentUpdated)="showSuccess($event)" />
```

Which work as expected. However in my student component I need to implement several events. e.g. saved, updated, deleted, confirmed, scheduled... etc

I was thinking instead of writing one event per line and calling them individually, is there a possibility that we can initialize array of events and execute them as needed. e.g.

```
  @Output() events:EventEmitter<any>[] = []
  for(var keyNum in arrayOfEvents)
  {
        var key = arrayOfEvents[keyNum];
        this.events.push(new EventEmitter())
  }
```

Then on certain event we emit the event based on index.

```
this.events[0].emit(e)
```

If we can then how can we do that and also how can we listen to that event on parent component ?

Comment: You're surely not using angular 4, 5 and 6 in the same project. I inferred from your [tag:angular5] that you're using 5.x, so I've edited the question to reflect that. It's helpful for now, and for future readers. Please correct that if it's not right.

Comment: @msanford thanks for updating the question. I mentioned all of them is because I started with Angular 4 updated to 5 and now moving towards 6. All of these versions are using same EventEmitter class. I assume people are awesome like you and understand what some one asked ;)

Comment: How kind of you. It's just that the most recent versions, especially 6, do have a lot of changes. Just helping keep things organized. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try have another approach to solve your issue, for example, you can restructure your output event data in a way that describe what kind of action your are executing

```
interface CustomEventData {
 kind : string,
value: any
}
```

in this way you going to have only eventEmitter output

```
@Output action:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

updated(e){
   this.action.emit({kind "updated", value : e });
}
```

in your parent component your function that handle the event will react based on the kind of event that is received

```
showSuccess({ kind , value}) {
    switch(kind)
       case "updated" ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, try to have only one EventEmitter and send an object with the type of action you want to perform (update, delete, .....and so on)

Comment: In addition, you have the event.type to identify the kind of event triggered

Comment: @Ricardo thanks for the answer, it should work as you mentioned. I will change my code.